# Factorial(code chef)

Tags: c++

please someone help me finding the error in this code. i've its python counterpart which is working fine, but when i code this in c++ , giving values(N) >=5 gives me an infinite loop.

> [in this problem, you have to find the no. of trailing zeros in the factorial of a given number]
>
> [here T is no. of test cases, N is the number, and z is output]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
long int T,N,Z;
cin>>T;
for(int x=0;x<T;x++){
    Z=0;
    cin>>N;
    for(int y=1;y<=N;y++){
        if(y%5==0){
            while(y/5!=0 && y%5==0){
                Z+=1;
                y/=5;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<Z<<endl;
    }
}
```

my python code is (which is working fine)

```
T=int(raw_input())
for x in range(1,T+1):
    Z=0
    N=int(raw_input())
    for y in range(1,N+1):
        if y%5==0:
            while y/5!=0 and y%5==0:
                Z=Z+1
                y=y/5
    print Z
```

Comment: NO MORE ANSWERS REQUIRED 

@dann_ thanks for correcting me :)

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
for(int y=1;y<=N;y++){
     int temp=y;
        if(temp%5==0){
            while(temp/5!=0 && temp%5==0){
                Z+=1;
                temp/=5;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out `y` being modified inside the `loop`:)

Answer (score 0):

your logic is not correct. Look at this, which i correctly submitted , hope it helps:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int tailing_zero(int n){
    int ans=0;
    int DIV=5;
        while(n/DIV >0){
        ans=ans+n/DIV;
        DIV=DIV*5;
    }
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    int run_count;
    cin>>run_count;
    int input[run_count];

    for(int i=0;i<run_count;i++){
        cin>>input[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<run_count;i++){
        cout<<tailing_zero(input[i])<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```